# bug in php type declaration of of function parameter

Tags: php, function, casting

Case: library uses code like this:

```
function setUnitPrice(?int $unitPrice)
    {
        return $unitPrice;
    }
```

and when I do like this:

```
$var1 = 0.58;
$var1 = $var1 * 100;
echo setUnitPrice($var1);
```

it comes out as 57 with php 7.2
with php 8 it shows warning of
Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 57.99999999999999 to int loses precision

I have never needed to round the float numbers in php before, can anybody explains this ?
to fix this, needs to have intaval(round($var1)) but this does not make any sense

Comment: I'm not sure where you think the bug is - PHP 8.1 just added a warning that implicit type conversion will result in a loss of precision (see https://3v4l.org/ttWuv). Like you say, the result was already 5.7. If you have a function that requires an int (and don't want to lose the precision), you'll need to round any float variables before they're used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var1 = 0.58;
$var1 = $var1 * 100;
echo setUnitPrice(round($var1));
```

> That is my proposition

Comment: This works. But I really feel like these kind of problems does not belong to php but are more javascript world's problems. I have been programming php for 15 years and never had this kind of problem before.

Answer (score 0):

$var1 has been declerated as float. If you do a var_dump of it, you will see.
But you can do

```
echo setUnitPrice((integer)$var1);
```

Comment: this does not work, it still one less